# Pass Id to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Lets say i have a site where I diaplay blog-posts in a list:
Model:

```
 public class BlogPost
    {
        public BlogPost()
        {
            Text = blogtext

            image = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to add a button on each blogpost that passes its Id to a controller (where i have a method that deletes it). Can someone show me how to make this button?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple google searc hwith "CRUD in ASP.Net MVC" would yield lot of results. Check this tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you'd create that button would be like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = model.Id})
```

`@Html.ActionLink` takes three arguments (in this usage): The first is the link text, the second is the action you want to send the link to, and the third is an object containing the data you want to send.

Comment: And you can use 4. Parameter @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = model.Id}, new {@class = "your css class"}); to make it look like button

Answer (score 2):

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "BlogPost"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

*Note: The difference between my answer and @sphanley's is how the action should respond. If you use POST (mine), then your action should delete the matching item immediately. If you use GET (sphanley's), then you should present a page to confirm, with a form much like in my answer that will delete only after it's posted. The rationale is that deletes (and anything else that is atomic) should happen only over POST (or a more specific verb such as PUT or DELETE) and not GET.*

Comment: Thank you for your example and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" name="Delete"  data-id="@Model.Id" class="RemoveLink"/>


    script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
                var deleteLink = $(this);
                $.post(
                    '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                        AddAntiForgeryToken({ id: deleteLink.attr('data-id') }))
                       .done(function () {
                           var parentRow = deleteLink.parents("tr:first");
                           parentRow.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                               parentRow.remove();
                           });
                       });
                return false;
            });

            AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
                data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
                return data;
            };
        });
    </script>
```

> use like this